# Summer Note Text Editor Don't Show Font Size in Blog Section in Journal Theme Open Cart 3

Tags: summernote, opencart-3

I'm using journal theme on opencart 3 , i have a strange problem i try to use summer note in blog posts page,
the font size option is not showing at all while in product page it is showing well,
i tried to look everywhere in files with no joy,

steps to reproduce (Add more if necessary):

1. install journal theme
2. head to blog, posts then add a new posts
3. editor will be there missing the font size option

opencart version Version 3.0.3.2

screenshot of issue

[image]

tried to look into summernote.js file tried to check the model file with no joy

expected result : editor showing font size option
what i get : full editor but only missing the font size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep invistigations i found that file named main.js is missing the phrase [[fontsize].[fontsize]], so i added it before [[fontcolor],[fontcolor]] and the font size box is once again showed in the summer note text editor

Comment: Hello, how do you enable summer note on blog posts in Journal theme? I'm trying and not getting anywhere